# animate height property tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Is there a way to animate the height property, this my simple code but the height isn't animated it just changed instantly

```
<div>
<a className="group  flex items-center w-full pr-4 pb-2 text-gray-600 transition-transform transform rounded-md hover:translate-x-1 focus:outline-none focus:ring collapsed" onClick={() => { setSecond(!secondElement) }}>
  <span className="ml-1 text-white text-xl group"> TITLE </span>
 </a>
</div>
<div className={`transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out transform ${!secondElement ? 'h-0' : 'h-auto'} bg-blue mt-2 space-y-2 px-7`}>
 <a
    role="menuitem"
    className="block p-2 text-sm text-white transition-colors duration-200 rounded-md dark:text-light dark:hover:text-light hover:text-gray-700">1</a>
 <a
  role="menuitem"
  className="block p-2 text-sm text-white transition-colors duration-200 rounded-md dark:hover:text-light hover:text-gray-700">2</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, Tailwind does not provide `transition-property` utilities for the `height` property. You'll need to add it to your `tailwind.config.js` file for the transition to work.

```js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            transitionProperty: {
                height: 'height'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

From Tailwind v3, you can now use an [arbitrary value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties) to generate a one-off `transition-property` on the fly, without changing your `tailwind.config.js` file.

```html
<div class="transition-[height]">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, when adding this in my config, it does work but only when going from h-0 to h-20 for example, it does not work form h-0 to h-auto. any idea why ?

Comment: It's [not recommended to use `auto` in transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#which_css_properties_can_be_transitioned) as the behaviour is unpredictable depending on the browser.